# SVG overlapping css triangle and colour change

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the worst problem to figure out: I am trying to change the colour of an SVG line as it crosses over a triangular background created with css.

I have tried to use a gradient, Which looks ok, but its not exactly the effect that I wanted.

I want it so that the svg stroke color changes to white as it crosses over into the red triangle taking into account the diagonal effect. I have come to the conclusion that it is impossible. I have tried layers and svgs but cant seem to find a way to do it.

My code:

```css
    .triangle2 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to left bottom, transparent 50%, #ed1d25 50%) repeat scroll 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 295px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 7;
    }
    .layer-id-6 {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    }
```

```html
<div class="triangle2"> </div>

    <div class="layer-id-6">

    <svg id="Layer_6" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" x="100%" y="100%" style="height: 100%">

    <g class="all">

    <line id="line25" x1="62.4%" y1="0" x2="62.4%" y2="100%" stroke="#000" style="fill:none; stroke-width: 20" />

    </g>
    </svg>
    </div>
```

Does anyone have any idea on how I can achieve this?

Please see my fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/xxfairydragonxx/1o40th7v/

Comment: Is it an actual requirement that the background triangle be HTML and the line be SVG? If both were SVG, you could probably achieve that using SVG filters. Also, for this stumbling on this question, you should probably include two pictures, one of what you currently get, and one of what you would like to get.

Answer (score 0):

You can get get what you want using `mix-blend-mode` and an extra copy of the SVG.

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.triangle2 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to left bottom, transparent 50%, #ed1d25 50%) repeat scroll 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 295px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 7;
}
.layer-id-6 {
    height: 100%;
 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.layer-id-6.version2 {
    mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle2"> </div>

<div class="layer-id-6">
  <svg id="Layer_6" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" x="100%" y="100%" style="height: 100%">
    <line id="line25" x1="62.4%" y1="0" x2="62.4%" y2="100%" stroke="#fff" style="fill:none; stroke-width: 20" />
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="layer-id-6 version2">
  <svg id="Layer_6" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" x="100%" y="100%" style="height: 100%">
    <line id="line25" x1="62.4%" y1="0" x2="62.4%" y2="100%" stroke="#fff" style="fill:none; stroke-width: 20" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

How this works is that we change the `<line>` colour to white, and apply a `mix-blend-mode: difference`. When blended with the white background, the white line becomes black and it appears as cyan over the red triangle.

Then we have another copy of SVG directly on top with `mix-blend-mode: color-dodge`.  This will keep the black part black and turn the cyan part white.

Voila.

The only snag is that (of course) IE and Edge don't support `mix-blend-mode`.